# Link kibana Dashboard to "Discover"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, kibana-5

I want to achieve a solution where

1. I have one dashboard ( a Data table )
2. If the user clicks on any particular row, It can redirect him "Discover" with same filter showing related documents

I did not find such any documents. Please see if anyone can give me a hand on this

Comment: You mean, when the user clicks a row from the Data Table?

Comment: yes .I want it when user clicks on Row

Comment: Not possible as far as I knew. Maybe you could try it with an external link to show the `Discover` from the `Dashboard`.

Answer (score 5):

The query actually stored in URL:
[image]

So simply go to discover page and past _q query from dashboard to it:
[image]