# Kibana dashboard page to Discover page On-Click

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, kibana-5, kibana-6

When I click on the Dashboard entity it should go to the Discover page and fetch me the exact log.

How can we achieve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link kibana Dashboard to "Discover"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823315/link-kibana-dashboard-to-discover)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you can't fetch exactly one record from a chart but you can narrow an area (to e.g. 1h/1min) on a chart and then when you go to Discover tab only records from the selected area will show up.

[image: Narrow an area]