# Kibana 7 - How can I jump from a Dashboard to the Discover Tab?

Tags: drilldown, kibana-7

While mindful of [this answer from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823315/link-kibana-dashboard-to-discover)...

For Kibana 7, is there an updated way to jump from a Dashboard to the Discover tab?

So that I can see the raw documents that support a visualization?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent, yes, there is a possibility to make dashboards interactive and open panel data to Dashboard, something what you are looking for. However, this will only work if your panel uses just one data view.
For more information on configuring this, please refer to: [explore-underlying-documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/explore-the-underlying-documents.html).

If you want to drill down into the documents from, lets say, data tables, you have that option as well, please read: [create-drilldowns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/create-drilldowns.html)